# Scrollspy table of content not following scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using materializecss scrollspy component on my website, the scrollspy link is working. But the only thing that bother me is the scrollspy's table of content didn't following the scroll position.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">
            <ul class="section table-of-contents">
                <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#information">Information Technology</a></li>
                <li><a href="#trade">Trade Marketing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
            <div id="about" class="section scrollspy">
                <h5>About Us</h5>
                <p><p>
            <span><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat temporibus sunt, velit reprehenderit fuga culpa. Nesciunt ducimus, maiores, alias, repellat corrupti dolorem, unde aliquid non itaque odit asperiores porro recusandae.</span>
            <span><br><br>Temporibus veniam veritatis nesciunt rem ipsum ab placeat magnam molestias nemo, officia officiis aut distinctio sint dolor. Quas facere atque animi, tenetur voluptas optio recusandae cumque nostrum commodi! Porro, aliquam.</span>
            <span><br><br>Corrupti vero quos quia voluptas officia, numquam doloribus, earum sunt adipisci repellat error aut, reiciendis rem id illo laborum eligendi facilis consectetur expedita dicta libero. Esse autem asperiores adipisci temporibus!</span>
            <span><br><br>Ea et voluptates, quibusdam incidunt excepturi consequatur, perspiciatis facere culpa quo rerum qui consectetur hic enim, iure repellendus! Harum voluptate expedita et nostrum, fugit distinctio ipsa sequi facere inventore, praesentium!</span>
            <span><br><br>Magnam optio impedit nostrum quos eligendi ea porro tempora! Pariatur consectetur ratione eius ad placeat dolor vero ipsa excepturi officia ullam sed culpa, quia quibusdam distinctio similique reiciendis laboriosam molestiae?</span>
            <span><br><br>Consectetur rerum aut ad quia optio iusto maxime, animi sunt. Sunt, totam, ipsam! Quibusdam harum aliquid ipsum! Minus dignissimos cum voluptate vel obcaecati nihil consequatur, rem in. Minima, ea, placeat.</span>
            <span><br><br>Facere dolorum reprehenderit praesentium! Esse velit numquam dolorum minus odio consectetur dolore illo aliquam aliquid illum veniam eligendi explicabo fuga quo aperiam, nam, deleniti sed natus rerum doloribus reprehenderit. Laudantium!</span>
            <span><br><br>Ab provident debitis enim iure nobis cupiditate consequuntur maxime numquam culpa iusto. Ipsa aperiam maxime quia accusamus, dolor, in dolore beatae perferendis incidunt, corrupti aut alias quaerat doloremque quae deleniti.</span>
        </p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div id="information" class="section scrollspy">
                <h5>Information Technology</h5>
                <p><p>
            <span><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat temporibus sunt, velit reprehenderit fuga culpa. Nesciunt ducimus, maiores, alias, repellat corrupti dolorem, unde aliquid non itaque odit asperiores porro recusandae.</span>
            <span><br><br>Temporibus veniam veritatis nesciunt rem ipsum ab placeat magnam molestias nemo, officia officiis aut distinctio sint dolor. Quas facere atque animi, tenetur voluptas optio recusandae cumque nostrum commodi! Porro, aliquam.</span>
            <span><br><br>Corrupti vero quos quia voluptas officia, numquam doloribus, earum sunt adipisci repellat error aut, reiciendis rem id illo laborum eligendi facilis consectetur expedita dicta libero. Esse autem asperiores adipisci temporibus!</span>
            <span><br><br>Ea et voluptates, quibusdam incidunt excepturi consequatur, perspiciatis facere culpa quo rerum qui consectetur hic enim, iure repellendus! Harum voluptate expedita et nostrum, fugit distinctio ipsa sequi facere inventore, praesentium!</span>
            <span><br><br>Magnam optio impedit nostrum quos eligendi ea porro tempora! Pariatur consectetur ratione eius ad placeat dolor vero ipsa excepturi officia ullam sed culpa, quia quibusdam distinctio similique reiciendis laboriosam molestiae?</span>
            <span><br><br>Consectetur rerum aut ad quia optio iusto maxime, animi sunt. Sunt, totam, ipsam! Quibusdam harum aliquid ipsum! Minus dignissimos cum voluptate vel obcaecati nihil consequatur, rem in. Minima, ea, placeat.</span>
            <span><br><br>Facere dolorum reprehenderit praesentium! Esse velit numquam dolorum minus odio consectetur dolore illo aliquam aliquid illum veniam eligendi explicabo fuga quo aperiam, nam, deleniti sed natus rerum doloribus reprehenderit. Laudantium!</span>
            <span><br><br>Ab provident debitis enim iure nobis cupiditate consequuntur maxime numquam culpa iusto. Ipsa aperiam maxime quia accusamus, dolor, in dolore beatae perferendis incidunt, corrupti aut alias quaerat doloremque quae deleniti.</span>
        </p> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div id="trade" class="section scrollspy">
                <h5>Trade Marketing</h5>
                <p><p>
            <span><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat temporibus sunt, velit reprehenderit fuga culpa. Nesciunt ducimus, maiores, alias, repellat corrupti dolorem, unde aliquid non itaque odit asperiores porro recusandae.</span>
            <span><br><br>Temporibus veniam veritatis nesciunt rem ipsum ab placeat magnam molestias nemo, officia officiis aut distinctio sint dolor. Quas facere atque animi, tenetur voluptas optio recusandae cumque nostrum commodi! Porro, aliquam.</span>
            <span><br><br>Corrupti vero quos quia voluptas officia, numquam doloribus, earum sunt adipisci repellat error aut, reiciendis rem id illo laborum eligendi facilis consectetur expedita dicta libero. Esse autem asperiores adipisci temporibus!</span>
            <span><br><br>Ea et voluptates, quibusdam incidunt excepturi consequatur, perspiciatis facere culpa quo rerum qui consectetur hic enim, iure repellendus! Harum voluptate expedita et nostrum, fugit distinctio ipsa sequi facere inventore, praesentium!</span>
            <span><br><br>Magnam optio impedit nostrum quos eligendi ea porro tempora! Pariatur consectetur ratione eius ad placeat dolor vero ipsa excepturi officia ullam sed culpa, quia quibusdam distinctio similique reiciendis laboriosam molestiae?</span>
            <span><br><br>Consectetur rerum aut ad quia optio iusto maxime, animi sunt. Sunt, totam, ipsam! Quibusdam harum aliquid ipsum! Minus dignissimos cum voluptate vel obcaecati nihil consequatur, rem in. Minima, ea, placeat.</span>
            <span><br><br>Facere dolorum reprehenderit praesentium! Esse velit numquam dolorum minus odio consectetur dolore illo aliquam aliquid illum veniam eligendi explicabo fuga quo aperiam, nam, deleniti sed natus rerum doloribus reprehenderit. Laudantium!</span>
            <span><br><br>Ab provident debitis enim iure nobis cupiditate consequuntur maxime numquam culpa iusto. Ipsa aperiam maxime quia accusamus, dolor, in dolore beatae perferendis incidunt, corrupti aut alias quaerat doloremque quae deleniti.</span>
        </p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the jquery

```
$('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
```

Or please check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/andhikaribrahim/pen/bBePJz) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon for my stupid question,
I just need to use [pushpin](http://materializecss.com/pushpin.html) components on the table of content.

Here's the jquery example:

```
$('.table-of-contents').pushpin({
    top: 900,
    bottom: 2000,
    offset: 0
});
```

Here's the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/andhikaribrahim/pen/bBePJz)

Comment: This doesn't seems to be an ideal solution. Have a look at my answer, you'll get to know the difference.

Comment: Please read my comment. You'll know the different if you're using it in a landing page website. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed` to `.table-of-contents`, Have a look at the updated **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNMOwK)**.

For your reference:

```
.table-of-contents {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Hi Saurav, good answer! Sorry, i can't accept your answer. I got this home > profile > etc page as the landing page structure. If I use your solution, the`.table-of-contents` will appear on the Home page section too, and i want to strict the `.table-of-contents` element just in the profile section. But it's a very nice workaround, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: @sunstation No problem! Just want to let you know the workaround.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for managing the scroll position of the content on click :

JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { });
            $('.scrollspy').scrollspy();
    </script>.
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">

                <ul class="section table-of-contents">
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#information">Information Technology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#trade">Trade Marketing</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
            <div id="about" class="section scrollspy">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p>
                    <span><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat temporibus sunt, velit reprehenderit fuga culpa. Nesciunt ducimus, maiores, alias, repellat corrupti dolorem, unde aliquid non itaque odit asperiores porro recusandae.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Temporibus veniam veritatis nesciunt rem ipsum ab placeat magnam molestias nemo, officia officiis aut distinctio sint dolor. Quas facere atque animi, tenetur voluptas optio recusandae cumque nostrum commodi! Porro, aliquam.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Corrupti vero quos quia voluptas officia, numquam doloribus, earum sunt adipisci repellat error aut, reiciendis rem id illo laborum eligendi facilis consectetur expedita dicta libero. Esse autem asperiores adipisci temporibus!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Ea et voluptates, quibusdam incidunt excepturi consequatur, perspiciatis facere culpa quo rerum qui consectetur hic enim, iure repellendus! Harum voluptate expedita et nostrum, fugit distinctio ipsa sequi facere inventore, praesentium!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Magnam optio impedit nostrum quos eligendi ea porro tempora! Pariatur consectetur ratione eius ad placeat dolor vero ipsa excepturi officia ullam sed culpa, quia quibusdam distinctio similique reiciendis laboriosam molestiae?</span>
                    <span><br><br>Consectetur rerum aut ad quia optio iusto maxime, animi sunt. Sunt, totam, ipsam! Quibusdam harum aliquid ipsum! Minus dignissimos cum voluptate vel obcaecati nihil consequatur, rem in. Minima, ea, placeat.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Facere dolorum reprehenderit praesentium! Esse velit numquam dolorum minus odio consectetur dolore illo aliquam aliquid illum veniam eligendi explicabo fuga quo aperiam, nam, deleniti sed natus rerum doloribus reprehenderit. Laudantium!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Ab provident debitis enim iure nobis cupiditate consequuntur maxime numquam culpa iusto. Ipsa aperiam maxime quia accusamus, dolor, in dolore beatae perferendis incidunt, corrupti aut alias quaerat doloremque quae deleniti.</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class=""></div>
            <div id="information" class="section scrollspy">
                <h2>Information Technology</h2>
                <p>
                    <span><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat temporibus sunt, velit reprehenderit fuga culpa. Nesciunt ducimus, maiores, alias, repellat corrupti dolorem, unde aliquid non itaque odit asperiores porro recusandae.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Temporibus veniam veritatis nesciunt rem ipsum ab placeat magnam molestias nemo, officia officiis aut distinctio sint dolor. Quas facere atque animi, tenetur voluptas optio recusandae cumque nostrum commodi! Porro, aliquam.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Corrupti vero quos quia voluptas officia, numquam doloribus, earum sunt adipisci repellat error aut, reiciendis rem id illo laborum eligendi facilis consectetur expedita dicta libero. Esse autem asperiores adipisci temporibus!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Ea et voluptates, quibusdam incidunt excepturi consequatur, perspiciatis facere culpa quo rerum qui consectetur hic enim, iure repellendus! Harum voluptate expedita et nostrum, fugit distinctio ipsa sequi facere inventore, praesentium!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Magnam optio impedit nostrum quos eligendi ea porro tempora! Pariatur consectetur ratione eius ad placeat dolor vero ipsa excepturi officia ullam sed culpa, quia quibusdam distinctio similique reiciendis laboriosam molestiae?</span>
                    <span><br><br>Consectetur rerum aut ad quia optio iusto maxime, animi sunt. Sunt, totam, ipsam! Quibusdam harum aliquid ipsum! Minus dignissimos cum voluptate vel obcaecati nihil consequatur, rem in. Minima, ea, placeat.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Facere dolorum reprehenderit praesentium! Esse velit numquam dolorum minus odio consectetur dolore illo aliquam aliquid illum veniam eligendi explicabo fuga quo aperiam, nam, deleniti sed natus rerum doloribus reprehenderit. Laudantium!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Ab provident debitis enim iure nobis cupiditate consequuntur maxime numquam culpa iusto. Ipsa aperiam maxime quia accusamus, dolor, in dolore beatae perferendis incidunt, corrupti aut alias quaerat doloremque quae deleniti.</span>
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class=""></div>
            <div id="trade" class="section scrollspy">
                <h2>Trade Marketing</h2>
                <p>
                    <span><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat temporibus sunt, velit reprehenderit fuga culpa. Nesciunt ducimus, maiores, alias, repellat corrupti dolorem, unde aliquid non itaque odit asperiores porro recusandae.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Temporibus veniam veritatis nesciunt rem ipsum ab placeat magnam molestias nemo, officia officiis aut distinctio sint dolor. Quas facere atque animi, tenetur voluptas optio recusandae cumque nostrum commodi! Porro, aliquam.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Corrupti vero quos quia voluptas officia, numquam doloribus, earum sunt adipisci repellat error aut, reiciendis rem id illo laborum eligendi facilis consectetur expedita dicta libero. Esse autem asperiores adipisci temporibus!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Ea et voluptates, quibusdam incidunt excepturi consequatur, perspiciatis facere culpa quo rerum qui consectetur hic enim, iure repellendus! Harum voluptate expedita et nostrum, fugit distinctio ipsa sequi facere inventore, praesentium!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Magnam optio impedit nostrum quos eligendi ea porro tempora! Pariatur consectetur ratione eius ad placeat dolor vero ipsa excepturi officia ullam sed culpa, quia quibusdam distinctio similique reiciendis laboriosam molestiae?</span>
                    <span><br><br>Consectetur rerum aut ad quia optio iusto maxime, animi sunt. Sunt, totam, ipsam! Quibusdam harum aliquid ipsum! Minus dignissimos cum voluptate vel obcaecati nihil consequatur, rem in. Minima, ea, placeat.</span>
                    <span><br><br>Facere dolorum reprehenderit praesentium! Esse velit numquam dolorum minus odio consectetur dolore illo aliquam aliquid illum veniam eligendi explicabo fuga quo aperiam, nam, deleniti sed natus rerum doloribus reprehenderit. Laudantium!</span>
                    <span><br><br>Ab provident debitis enim iure nobis cupiditate consequuntur maxime numquam culpa iusto. Ipsa aperiam maxime quia accusamus, dolor, in dolore beatae perferendis incidunt, corrupti aut alias quaerat doloremque quae deleniti.</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

refer to [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOXxVj)

Comment: Sorry, please read other answers before you submit any. I already answered my own question. And your answer doesn't seems to be valid because I already put the scrollspy initiation on my codepen. If by other mean that I had any typo on the initialization, you can see the scrollspy documentation in here http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html

Comment: Please check the codepen it will fix the scrolling problem in the html

Comment: you have to use `scrollspy` in place of `scrollSpy`. refer to this [document](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy/blob/master/examples/fixednav.html) for more information

Comment: No it's not. And `.table-of-contents` in your codepen didn't even working if you're using that init because it's outside the `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Thank you for your feedback.